# Beginner Problem with reading out data from a list

Tags: powershell

Im pretty new to SharePoint and PowerShell in General.

So currently I'm trying to get data out of a list to fill in missing Information in a library.

So I have the List Customers("Kundenakte") and the Library Orders "Bestellungen"
In Orders there is a document that only has A customer number, but not customer Name. in Custerms there is the Name and the number.

Code:

```
$SiteUrl = "TestSite"
$ListName = "Bestellungen"
$DocName ="Test.txt"

$Url = Get-SPWeb $SiteUrl
$List = $Url.Lists[$ListName]
$Items = $List.GetItembyID(7)
$KundenNr = $Items["ecsKundenNr"]

$List2 = $Url.Lists["Kundenakte"]
$Items2 = $List2.Items

foreach($item in $items2)
{
    if($Item["ecsKundenNr"] -eq $KundenNr)
    {
        $KundenName = $Item["ecsKundename"]
    }
}
Write-Host $KundenName

$List = $Url.Lists[$ListName]
$Items = $List.GetItembyID(7)
$Items["ecsKundenname"] = $KundenName

$Items.Update()
```

But I dont get to fill Kundenname.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is type of column 'ecsKundename' in Bestellungen list

Comment: just a single Line of Text.

Comment: can you define "$KundenName" above foreach with empty string lik

$KundenName = "" and check

Comment: and datatype of 'ecsKundenNr' in 'ecsKundename' in 'Kundenakte' List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the column "ecsKundenname" exits in your orders list(Bestellungen) and also verify the internal name is same you have used in your script.

Also are you getting the Kundenname value after the iteration?

Comment: So I verified that I used the correct internal names. 

I defined "$Kundenname" with "Test" before the foreach Loop now, and the Loop clears the Content of "$Kundenname". So I take the fault lays in the Loop, and I will look further into it

Comment: it was indeed a column Name that I renamend! Thank you so much!